# traverse the dom an select each inputbox pair in order to create js object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding dynamic number of input boxes inside view from 
        selection combobox.

If I choose 1 from combobox I add two input boxes inside view, 2 adds 4, so one selection adding one pair of input boxes which has it's unique id's:

```
<input id="MyTextBox1" type="text">
<input id="MyTextBoxComp1" type="text">        

<input id="MyTextBox2" type="text">
<input id="MyTextBoxComp2" type="text">
```

... and so on.

Let's say that I want to create js object from values in this inputboxes. How can I traverse the dom an select each inputbox pair in order to create js object, for example:

```
var myObj = { propOne:"x", propTwo:y };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's some like this what you want?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var n = 0;
                $('#combobox').change(function() {
                    for(i = 0; i < $(this).val(); i++) {
                        $('#view').append(
                            '<input id="MyTextBox' + n + '" type="text"> ' +
                            '<input id="MyTextBoxComp' + n + '" type="text">');
                        n++;
                    }
                });

                $('#show-json').click(function() {
                    var r = [];
                    for(var i = 0; true; i++) {

                        var MyTextBoxI = $('#MyTextBox' + i);
                        var MyTextBoxCompI = $('#MyTextBoxComp' + i);

                        if(MyTextBoxI.length) {
                            var propI = {};
                            propI['propOne' + i] = MyTextBoxI.val();
                            propI['propTwo' + i] = MyTextBoxCompI.val();
                            r.push(propI);
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    $('#json').html(JSON.stringify(r));
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            input {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="combobox">
            <option value="0" selected>None</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <div id="view">

        </div>
        <button id="show-json">Show JSON</button>
        <pre id="json">

        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to get every pair values you should do something like this :

```
$i=1;
obj = $('#MyTextBox'+$i);
objComp = $('#MyTextBoxComp'+$i);

while(obj.length) {
    value1 = obj.val();
    value2 = ibjComp.val(); 
    // do stuff
    i++;
    obj = $('#MyTextBox'+$i);
    objComp = $('#MyTextBoxComp'+$i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating them automatically, tag the inputs in some way, e.g.:

```
<input id="MyTextBox1" data-related="#MyTextBoxComp1" type="text">
<input id="MyTextBoxComp1" type="text">
```

Script:

```
var $textBox1 = $("#MyTextBox1");
var myObj = { propOne: $textBox1.val(), propTwo: $($textBox1.data("related")).val() };
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wq3998wu/)

Or, if you can't change your existing DOM:

```
var $textBox1 = $("#MyTextBox1");
var myObj = { propOne: $textBox1.val(), propTwo: $textBox1.next("[id^=MyTextBoxComp]").val() };
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f546jgpw/1/)

But the latter assumes that the DOM structure will never change.

Comment: @ RGraham there are 4 `input ` in post

Comment: *dynamic number of input boxes*. They don't specify how they're selecting  `MyTextBox1` in the first place, so I will leave that up to them.